# PHP email message not working

Tags: php, email

When I edited my PHP code to send a message, and a from field, the from field worked then the message didn't. How could I have it so the message would be in the body of the email while working with the from field? Here is my code.

```
<?php    
$headers  = "Contact: ".$_POST['contact']."\r\n";
$headers .= "BCC: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Your Company <your_company@example.com>\r\n";

mail("Your Memory", $thank_you,$headers, $message);
?>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use `$thank_you` or `$message` as the body of the email?

Comment: Are you working on a `localhost`?

Comment: What are the contents of `$to_visitor`? We cannot see where you set that variable.

Comment: oh that's nothing i forgot to delete that!

Comment: I think you might want to take a good look at the [mail()](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) method and possibly how functions work in general. You can't just remove arguments or add them arbitrarily and expect it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parameters are messed up.  The fifth parameter where you have `$mesage` is supposed to be extra options  passed to the SMTP server. Looks like you might intend to have `$message` where you have `$thank_you`.

```
mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $message, $headers);
```

Comment: So how could I fix that? Please excuse me, I am a total newbie to PHP

Comment: @BenThomson See the `mail()` call I already added, probably while you were typing your comment.

Comment: Thanks for all the help, but when I send a message it has no content, what am I doing wrong?! Here's the code: <?php    
 $headers  = "Contact: ".$_POST['contact']."\r\n";
 $headers .= "BCC: ".$_POST['email']."\r\n";
 $headers .= "From: Your Company <your_company@example.com>\r\n";
mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $message, $headers);
 ?>

Comment: @BenThomson If it has no content, I would assume `$message` is empty. Check that it has the value you expect it to have (the message body)

Answer (score 0):

Your parameters are in the wrong order... From [PHP.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

```
bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] )
```

So you'll want:

```
mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $message ,$headers);
```

Not sure what $thank_you is, but you'll need to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The message parameter for `mail()` is the third parameter. If you want to use your `$message` as the message you need to change your `mail()` call to:

```
mail($to_visitor, "Your Memory", $message, $headers);
```